# id gets null value while inserting form into database using laravel 8

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to insert data into database.

So I have the following view and script for adding data into database :

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });

    $('#submit').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "{{route('ajout_projet.store')}}",
        method: "POST",
        data: $('#projetform').serialize(),
        type: 'json',
        success: function(e) {
          console.log(e)
        },
        error: function(error) {
          console.log(error)
        }

      });

    });

  }) <
  /script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form method="POST" id="projetform" class="myForms" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type="hidden" id="id_hidden" name="id_projet" />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="mb-4">Projet</h5>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAddress">Numéro de projet</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numero_projet" name="numero_projet" placeholder="Description">
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputState">Client</label>
              <select id="id_client" class="form-control" name="id_client">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                @foreach($clients as $client)
                <option data-id="{{$client->id_client}}" value="{{$client->id_client}}">{{$client->client}}</option>
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputState">Agence de Conseil</label>
              <select id="id_agence_conseil" class="form-control" name="id_agence_conseil">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                @foreach($agences_conseil as $agence_conseil)
                <option data-id="{{$agence_conseil->id_agence_conseil}}" value="{{$agence_conseil->id_agence_conseil}}">{{$agence_conseil->agence_conseil}}</option>
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputState">Agence de Production</label>
              <select id="id_agence_production" class="form-control" name="id_agence_production">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                @foreach($agences_production as $agence_production)
                <option data-id="{{$agence_production->id_agence_production}}" value="{{$agence_production->id_agence_production}}">{{$agence_production->agence_production}}</option>
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="inputState">Agence de Casting</label>
              <select id="id_agence_casting" class="form-control" name="id_agence_casting">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                @foreach($agences_casting as $agence_casting)
                <option data-id="{{$agence_casting->id_agence_casting}}" value="{{$agence_casting->id_agence_casting}}">{{$agence_casting->agence_casting}}</option>
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Description">
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="date_tournage">Date de tournage</label>
              <div class="input-group date">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_tournage" name="date_tournage">
                <span class="input-group-text input-group-append input-group-addon" id="spanEstPaymentDate">
                                            <i class="simple-icon-calendar"></i>
                                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="date_premiere_diffusion">Date de première diffusion</label>
              <div class="input-group date">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_premiere_diffusion" name="date_premiere_diffusion">
                <span class="input-group-text input-group-append input-group-addon" id="spanEstPaymentDate">
                                                    <i class="simple-icon-calendar"></i>
                                    </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-xl-8 col-left">
      <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-body">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-1 add_new_frm_field_btn">Ajouter un nouveau casting</button>
          </br>
          </br>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">

              <div class="card mb-4 form_field_outer  ">
                <div class="card-body form_field_outer_row outer" data-index="1">
                  <input type="hidden" id="id_projet_casting" name="id_projet_casting" />
                  <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
                      <select class="form-control maintCostField" name="rows[1][id_casting]" id="id_casting">
                        <option selected>Choose...</option>
                        @foreach($castings as $casting)
                        <option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label for="inputState">Type de contrat</label>
                      <select id="id_modele_contrat" class="form-control" name="rows[1][id_modele_contrat]">
                        <option selected>Choose...</option>
                        @foreach($models_contrat as $model_contrat)
                        <option data-id="{{$model_contrat->id_modele_contrat}}" value="{{$model_contrat->id_modele_contrat}}">{{$model_contrat->modele_contrat}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body ">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-xl-4 col-right">

      <div class="card mb-4 casting_details ">
        <div class="card-body casting_details2 ">
          <div class="d-flex flex-row mb-3 ">
            <!-- Pictures ot the selected casting will come here-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And I'm using the following controller for saving data into database:

```
$projets = new Projet();
                 $projets->numero_projet = $request['numero_projet'];
                 $projets->id_client = $request['id_client'];
                 $projets->id_agence_conseil = $request['id_agence_conseil'];
                 $projets->id_agence_production = $request['id_agence_production'];
                 $projets->id_agence_casting = $request['id_agence_casting'];
                 $projets->description = $request['description'];
                 $projets->date_tournage = $date;
                 $projets->date_premiere_diffusion = $datee_diffusion;
                 $projets->id_filiale = Auth::user()->id_filiale;
                 $projets->id_createur = Auth::user()->id;
                 $projets->save();
```

The problem is when I did `dd($projets->id);` I get null.

**update**

Why when I did that in my Controller I get : `message: "Creating default object from empty value"` in this line :

```
$projets_castings->id_projet = $projets->id_projet;
```

Controller:

```
$projets = new Projet();
                 $projets->numero_projet = $request['numero_projet'];
                 $projets->id_client = $request['id_client'];
                 $projets->id_agence_conseil = $request['id_agence_conseil'];
                 $projets->id_agence_production = $request['id_agence_production'];
                 $projets->id_agence_casting = $request['id_agence_casting'];
                 $projets->description = $request['description'];
                 $projets->date_tournage = $date;
                 $projets->date_premiere_diffusion = $datee_diffusion;
                 $projets->id_filiale = Auth::user()->id_filiale;
                 $projets->id_createur = Auth::user()->id;
                 $projets->save();
                 $projets->refresh();
                  /*dd($projets->id_projet);*/

                  
                 $projets_castings = new Projet_Casting();
                 $projets_castings->id_projet = $projets->id_projet;
                 $projets_casting->id_casting = $request['id_casting'];
                 $projets_casting->id_contrat = $request['id_modele_contrat'];
                 $projets_casting->save();
```

the id_project in database is an auto increment , but I want to get the value of the id_project from the form while inserting data into database

Why the value of the `id_projet` is null ?

What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: You probably just need to rehydrate your model: `$projets->refresh(); dd($projets->id)`

Comment: Is the incrementing column name `id` or `id_projet`?

Comment: its name is `id_projet`

Comment: Then you'd need to access `$projets->id_projet`

Comment: @YaakovAinspan , please check my update

Comment: Try adding this to the model: `protected $primaryKey = 'id_projet'`

Comment: I already did it